# how to export names when package name is different from file name?

Tags: perl

I have a file Scanners.pm which contains 2 packages. I want both these packages to export some names. I do not want those packages be in separate files, I want them to be in one file.

When I write

```
package SCAN;

use Exporter;
our @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT    = qw(@SCANNERS @NAMES %NAMES name_index process_scanners);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw();
```

and then in the calling .pl file

```
use Scanner;
```

the names in the `@EXPORT` list are not exported. How I do that?

Comment: Why do they need to be in the same file

Comment: @justintime, the modules evolve over time and have to stay together. Keeping them in one file is one way to ensure that they match each other and stay together as they are copied around.

Comment: Why do they "have to stay together". Systems evolve and sometimes you need to reorganise the code for maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom import sub for your Scanner package.  [Exporting Without Using Exporter's import Method](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#Exporting-Without-Using-Exporter%27s-import-Method).

Note, this code only will work if the user relies on the default @EXPORT only.  If you want them to be able to specify what functions they want, then you'll have to filter before calling export_to_level.

```
package Scanner;

use Exporter;
our @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT    = qw(scannersub);

use strict;
use warnings;

sub import {
    Scanner->export_to_level(1, @_);
    ScannerTwo->export_to_level(1, @_);
}

sub scannersub {
    print "scanner->sub says hi\n";
}


package ScannerTwo;

use Exporter;
our @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT    = qw(scannertwosub);

sub scannertwosub {
    print "scannertwo->sub says hi\n";
}

1;

__END__
```

and your script

```
use Scanner;

use strict;
use warnings;

scannersub();
scannertwosub();

1;

__END__
```

Finally, I would be remis if I didn't mention that this isn't a great idea on it's surface.  Future maintainers of this code will not easily be able to trace these subs.  So whatever your reason for wanting them in the same file but different packages, I suspect there is a better solution.

Comment: `use Scanner` invokes `Scanner::import`, so that is where you need to export symbols from a second package.